# Can't set a Column header sortUnSort icon in Angular ag-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

Well, basically what it says: While according to the documentation, the attribute sortUnSort defaults to no image, I don't seem to be able to include any icons. It sounds like something absolutely unimportant, but I really need such a solution.

constructor() {

```
// TODO: The table has to be build dynamically. 

this.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    { headerName: 'County', field: 'country'},
    { headerName: 'ModelName', field: 'model' },
    { headerName: 'Address', field: 'address' },
    { headerName: 'Equipment Number', field: 'equipmentNo' }
  ],

rowData: [
  { country: 'Germany', model: 'Add', address: "xxxxx", equipmentNo: 1551599181 },
  { country: 'Poland', model: 'Mondeo', address: "xxxxx", equipmentNo: 8907234234 },
  { country: 'France', model: 'Boxter', address: "xxxxx", equipmentNo: 9872342344 },
  { country: 'Austria', model: 'Boxter', address: "xxxxx", equipmentNo: 239874244 }
],

rowSelection: 'single',

icons: {
    sortAscending: '<i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
    sortDescending: '<i class="fa fa-sort-amount-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
    sortUnSort: '<i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
}

}
```

The other icon attributes, work perfectly fine and render the icons as they should as seen here...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, super shameful moment for me... again. It's so easy, it hurts and I can only blame my shortsightness for it.

There is literally a method for it and the developers themselves make the mention, that the none-sort icon is - by default - disabled. Simply add in your gridOptions
the value

```
unSortIcon:true
```

And you're golden.